# Excel Get & Transform CSV: Is there a way to import only new data from a CSV to the data model

Tags: excel, csv, powerquery

I currently have a query in Excel that I use to import data from a YearToDate CSV file, it's transformed and loaded as a connection only.
I presently have two cells that indicate the last entry and another that counts the number of rows of data from my query. I include this info on a worksheet.
The CSV is updated once daily and the query refreshes the data to my spreadsheet, where I have various pivot tables and measures.
The file is obviously getting bigger every day. I am filtering much of the data out that I don't need, however the query takes a long time.

So the question is, is it possible to configure the query to see what the last entry was and refresh or apply the query to new data only. Meaning loading only from the last entry and not reloading the whole dataset?

Maybe it actually does this and I don't realize it, but it just seems to be slow. The CSV is on a shared network folder.

Also, it possibly needs to load the whole CSV before it can look at the data, in which case my question is answered.

Thank you for any assistance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've answered your own question: the entire CSV file needs to be imported before any filters can be applied.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new, fast query that just gets the last row, and then refresh the big one only if needed. The new one could work like this:

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\test.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=1, Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Kept Last Rows" = Table.LastN(#"Changed Type", 1)
in
    #"Kept Last Rows"
```

performance is always dependent on the transformations you make, so this one should be much faster than your full query

EDIT I misunderstood your question, you basically want a delta refresh for PowerPivot, correct? that's not supported, and the model does refresh in full

Comment: Both correct, I realize that the data set needs to be loaded before anything can be done. Stachu, I wish I knew what a delta refresh was, which I'm now going to try find out about. But thank you for your input here above. It's not wasted on me.